# How should I be setting browscap.ini file

Tags: php, browser-detection, browscap

I downloaded the browscap.ini file and then pasted it to the directory "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\extras" and i went to php.ini file and made these changes there:

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = extras/browscap.ini
```

and then i restarted the server, and typed the following code into temp.php file:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "<br><br>";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

now the output is like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4

Warning: get_browser(): browscap ini directive not set in C:\wamp\www\functions\browser.php on line 4
```

am i missing something? please provide some solution, and sorry if i am unable to make you understand

Comment: Restarting the browser might be insufficient. PHP runs in the local webserver. Restart that one.

Comment: sorry, i meant i restarted server, i mistakenly typed browser, it should be server.

Comment: @mario, i dont know about time zone, i wanted to use get_browser which is not working.

Comment: @mario i don't believe this is a duplicate

Comment: @Baba: True. Not this one. Seems more like editing discrepancy now. (Would have otherwise closevoted as too localized.)

Comment: Could this setting be changed during script execution, with `ini_set`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are to use the `Full PATH` and restart your server when you are done

Example

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
```

Comment: thanks. it worked, but default was extra\browscap.ini so there may be any alternative??

Comment: Yes, you can find several browscap alternatives at https://browscap.org/

Answer (score 15):

on linux server

```
wget http://browscap.org/stream?q=Lite_PHP_BrowsCapINI -O /etc/php.d/browscap.ini

[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = "/etc/php.d/browscap.ini"
```

Answer (score 4):

use this code for install, tested on mint and debian

```
wget http://browscap.org/stream?q=Lite_PHP_BrowsCapINI -O /etc/php7/apache2/browscap.ini
sudo echo -e "[browscap]\n  browscap = '/etc/php7/apache2/browscap.ini'" >> php.ini
sudo service apache2 reload
```

replace php7 for you PHP version

Answer (score 3):

This is work for me on MacBook.

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = "/usr/local/etc/browscap.ini"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** browsecap file is not default configuration, and disabled by default. If you setting it, make sure you call **get_browser()** safely in your scripts to avoid warnings on other installations by checking if it is available to be called:

```
if (!ini_get('browscap')) {

    // Not set, use other custom func to detect browser:
    $browser = get_browser_manually();
} else {

    // Browsecap.ini was set, use it:
    $browser = get_browser(null, true);
}
```

See my complete answer related to broswer detection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69065259/2213708).