# jQuery fallback for background image transition

Tags: jquery, background-image, css-transitions, fallback

I have a script that rotates between an array of preloaded images at a set interval to change the background image. I'm using transitions (`transition: background-image 2s ease`) to make the rotation crossfade, but this is currently only supported in Chrome.

I can modify the script using jQuery to animate the element to fade out, change the source and then fade back in, but enabling this script overrides Chrome's behaviour. As a side/alternate question, is it possible to emulate crossfading using jQuery?

How can I allow Chrome to use the CSS transition and force all other browsers to use the jQuery animation?

I am using Modernizr, but I don't think the feature detection would work as most other modern browsers get the `csstransitions` class even if they don't support certain specific transitions like `background-image`, but I would be happy if someone could prove me wrong.

Comment: U can use navigator object to find if the client is chrome browser ad put your code under the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use navigator object to find if the client is chrome browser ad put your code under the condition.

```
$.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 
if($.browser.chrome){
/*code for chrome browser*/

}
else{
/*code for other browser*/
}
```

hope this help

Comment: I like this approach. The first line's using a regular expression, in case you're wondering about the wonky syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I'm not sure how elegant this is, but I used your code as a framework and instead added a PHP check at the bottom of my index.php file as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047894/how-to-detect-google-chrome-as-the-user-agent-using-php

I then added a condition within the function to check for that global variable (isChrome) and do the appropriate code accordingly.