# How can you detect the chrome browser in PHP7.0+?

Tags: php, google-chrome

I am upgrading from php 5.5 and this worked, but not sure what I can use now to detect the google chrome browser?

```
function is_chrome()
{
    return(eregi("chrome", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
}

if(is_chrome())
{ 
  $chrome = 'You are using Google Chrome Browser.';
} else{
  $chrome = 'hide';
}
```

Comment: "
Warning

This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Alternatives to this function include:

    preg_match()

" http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php

Comment: I will see if I can find an example with preg_match().  I appreciate the tip.

Comment: if you just use get_browser() no regular expression is required

Comment: I am trying that out right now! :)

Comment: You can those answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047894/how-to-detect-google-chrome-as-the-user-agent-using-php

Comment: echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$browser = get_browser();
print_r($browser);